# Pivot column to rows in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

Looking for any solution to convert columns to rows.

I have my columns as [CA_resp],[CA_spen],[TX_resp],[TX_spen],[PA_resp],[PA_spen],these columns need to be converted to rows.
all the states (CA,TX,PA) should go into [market] column,[resp] need to be other column [spen] need to be other column.

Here is an example: I have a table with the following schema:

```
 CREATE TABLE stage.test(
         id int null,
        [month] [varchar](255) NULL, 
        [year] [float] NULL,
        CA_resp [float] NULL,
        CA_spen [money] NULL,
        TX_resp [float] NULL, 
        TX_spen [money] NULL,
        PA_resp [float] NULL,   
        PA_spen [money] NULL)
    
    INSERT into stage.test
    values(1,    'jan', 2022,222,`enter code here`450,111,450,444,550)
```

I want my output to be.

```
    ID, month,year, market, resp ,spen
    1    jan    2022    CA  222     350
    1    jan    2022    TX  111     450
    1    jan    2022    PA  444     550
```

I tried using Pivot and didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot use [Pivot](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/from-using-pivot-and-unpivot?view=sql-server-ver15) in your case, since you don't have enough rows/columns.
You need to "create" rows, which can be done using seperate select statements combined with [union](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/set-operators-union-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15).
I prefer to [cross join](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-query/cross-join) them so you don't have to repeat the same columns in every select.
But you can also use the select with union direct, it's up to you

```
select t.id, t.month, t.year, v.market, v.CA_resp as resp, v.CA_spen as spen
from   test t
  cross join (select 'CA' as market, CA_resp, CA_spen from test
              union
              select 'TX' as market, TX_resp, TX_spen from test
              union
              select 'PA' as market, PA_resp, PA_spen from test
             ) v
```

The result is

| id | month | year | market | resp | spen |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | jan | 2022 | CA | 222 | 450.0000 |
| 1 | jan | 2022 | PA | 444 | 550.0000 |
| 1 | jan | 2022 | TX | 111 | 450.0000 |

Here is the [DBFiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=b0eca445017d64189869e22022e1df52)

Or you could just put all fields in 3 selects with union, the result is the same just use what you like best

```
select id, month, year, 'CA' as market, CA_resp as resp, CA_spen as spen from test
union
select id, month, year, 'TX' as market, TX_resp, TX_spen from test
union
select id, month, year, 'PA' as market, PA_resp, PA_spen from test
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use 3 queries with `UNION ALL`. This approach is very efficient because we output 3 simple queries one after the other. There is no join or other comparison of data.
(A join with `UNION` without all is a different story because it compares the queries to eliminate duplicates.)

```
     CREATE TABLE stagetest(
              id int null,
             [month] [varchar](255) NULL, 
             [year] [float] NULL,
             CA_resp [float] NULL,
             CA_spen [money] NULL,
             TX_resp [float] NULL, 
             TX_spen [money] NULL,
             PA_resp [float] NULL,   
             PA_spen [money] NULL);
         
         INSERT into stagetest
         values(1,    'jan', 2022,222,450,111,450,444,550);
     --ID, month,year, market, resp ,spen
      --   1    jan    2022    CA  222     350
     --    1    jan    2022    TX  111     450
     --    1    jan    2022    PA  444
     SELECT id, [month], [year], 'CA' market, ca_resp Resp, ca_spen Spen
     from stagetest
     union all
     SELECT id, [month], [year], 'PA', pa_resp, pa_spen
     from stagetest
     union all
     SELECT id, [month], [year], 'TX', tx_resp, tx_spen
     from stagetest;
```

| id | month | year | market | Resp | Spen |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | jan | 2022 | CA | 222 | 450.0000 |
| 1 | jan | 2022 | PA | 444 | 550.0000 |
| 1 | jan | 2022 | TX | 111 | 450.0000 |

fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=a909357ebe484705be1fffce880e2e88)

Comment: Please check your answers on formatting next time the answer was very hard to read as it was. I have corrected the formatting it is up to you to finish it off the way you want it.